# Need bootstrap input field background image to be "full bleed", no border

Tags: css, input, background-image

I have this form:

[image]

It doesn't matter how large I make the images, or how much I fiddle with the size of the fields, the white border is there, always. How do I make it so the white border is not around the top, left, and bottom of the blue icon on the left side of each input field.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form role="form" class="">
    <fieldset class="">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <input type="email" class="form-control no-shadow margin-bottom20 email-field form-group" id="InputEmail" placeholder="email" required="" style="border-radius:0px;">
            <input type="password" class="form-control no-shadow password-field" id="InputPassword" placeholder="password" required="" style="border-radius:0px;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn margin-top45 btn-lg bg-transparent bg-transparent-hover no-shadow text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" style="border : solid 3px #99cc33;color:#ffffff;">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.email-field
{
    background-image: url('../images/email-input-icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: null;
    background-clip: border-box;
}

.password-field
{
    background-image: url('../images/password-input-icon.png');
}

.margin-bottom20
{
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.form-control
{
    color: #34495e;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.467;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 66px;
    height: 54px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
    transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.form-group
{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-group.focus .form-control, .form-control:focus
{
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: what is absolute link for "background-image: url('../images/email-input-icon.png');"?..I mean for all background images?

Comment: Have you tried adding margin:0; to the images? and or removing padding on the inputs?

Comment: try `background-size: contain` or give a size.

Comment: Unless you are able to provide a [mcve] of your problem, all we can do is grasp at straws. Most probably, what you are showing is a border. Inspecting that element and its parents is the key to finding the `CSS` rule that sets it. After that, it's as simple as either modifying that rule wherever it is in your project or writing a stronger rule that would override the `margin` property of that element (or `box-shadow`, or some `background` props combo, or `outline` or whatever else it might be).

Comment: @repzero: Thank you. The absolute link is currently http://localhost/images/email-input-icon.png. Same path for the password-input-icon.png.  


@MathiasHaugsbø: Thank you. I just now tried adding margin:0 to the images. The only padding on the inputs currently is the padding to move the placeholder text to the right. That is: `padding: 8px 12px 8px 66px;` But, it didn't work.  

@Maxali: Thank you. `background-size: contain` didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: Thanks for your suggestions. Also, I apologize for the incomplete nature of this question. Normally I don't post these unless I have something you can look at online and fiddle with using Inspector. This is for a site not yet released and that can't be shown to the public, so this is the best I could do. I've been staring at the problem so long and trying so many things, that I thought maybe even these suggestions would get me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.form-control, .form-control:focus {
  border-color:Transparent;
}
```

Comment: This came really close! It fixed the bottom border of the "password" field, at least. Now to figure out why only that bottom border and not the others.

Comment: Adding the following to .form-control did the trick:  

`    .form-control {
        border-color: transparent;
        border: none !important;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom: none;
    }`

Comment: border-bottom: 0px; is actually border-bottom-width: 0px; just so as you know.